# Dispersity of synthetic DNA

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, synthesis, dna-rna

Recently I was reading an article about DNA nanostructures and I was wondering--

I know that DNA in living systems is monodisperse, but when we make DNA synthetically, is it truly monodisperse or does the dispersity vary depending on how it is synthesized?

If it has the same molecular structure, why does the fact that it's made synthetically change the dispersity?

Thanks

Comment: Ten DNA strands of different lenght are still DNA. What do you want to *do* with it?

Comment: Two different cells will replicate DNA with different degrees of fidelity (dispersity, variability), depending on the capabilities and state of the DNA replication and mismatch repair machinery. In the same way, two labs will produce synthetic DNA of different quality depending on a lot of factors including the type of available equipment, chemicals, and  (not least) method of *purification*. Everything is error-prone, it's a fact of life. Check the message I just wrote and see if you can't find an error (despite my incredible innate error checking machinery). You probably will.